# Logging level for loggerName (org.optaplanner.core) cannot be determined

Tags: java, slf4j, optaplanner

Getting a exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logging level for loggerName (org.optaplanner.core) cannot be determined", when trying to use the benchmarker.

How do I fix this? There's very little about this in the docs, except something to do with a `logback.xml` file...?

Comment: What's the full stracktrace? Also share `mvn dependency:tree | grep "log"`.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a problem with the logger itself, not Optaplanner. I switched out logback-nop with logback-classic.